# Lost data from Dotcloud NGINX server

Tags: nginx, dotcloud

I have a Django application running on Dotcloud.

When downloading data users **intermittently** get an error like this -
  `IOError: Attempted to read 45607 bytes from the buffer but only 35459 remain`

The server components are NGINX, uWSGI, Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.
The actual client request is made via a PyAMF call but behind the scenes PyAMF uses an http POST so nothing complicated there.

No error log (that I can find) is generated or the server.

To test this I created a Python script which fetches the same data at predetermined interval (say 5 seconds). It will run successfully for up to 100+ times then will fail with an error like the one above.

- It does **not** appear to be related to memory usage - according to the Dotcloud dashboard the server is well within its limits.
- It does **not** appear to be related to server load - running two instances of the script doesn't make the errors more frequent.
- Larger downloads **do** fail more frequently.
- It **doesn't** appear related to the clients' site or software.

I have read all I can on lost packets and lost connections for NGINX and Dotcloud without luck.
Can anyone make a suggestion as to how I track this issue down?

Comment: The error logs will be in `/var/log/nginx` and `/var/log/supervisor` (since you're running python) -- anything interesting there?

Comment: No, nothing in the NGINX logs. I tried changing the debug level on our QA server to DEBUG, but couldn't get it to work - the server wouldn't start. Perhaps Dotcloud have intentionally tried to prohibit changing the NGINX logging level.

Comment: The standard services don't allow you to change the logging level, but you can create a custom service with Nginx and fully-control the logging (e.g. [nginx-on-dotcloud](https://github.com/dotcloud/nginx-on-dotcloud))